# How to bundle dojo library in liferay which can be used in all themes

Tags: javascript, dojo, liferay

I have a liferay theme which which also embeds DOJO library in it. Since DOJO is fairly big in size and takes lot of time to parse the liferay theme and deploy it, can we keep the dojo as a seperate bundle in liferay and use it in any theme which we create?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom build of Dojo at [build.dojotoolkit.org](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/). With this tool you can create a custom build with only the modules you need and even compress it into a single file if I recall correctly.

Some other guides that might be useful are the [Creating builds](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/build/) tutorial and the [Build system reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/).

Answer (score 0):

How did you integrate dojo into your theme? I assume you'll need a reference somewhere in the `HTML HEAD` area - and you don't need to reference it from within your theme, but can reference any external source. If you reference the same external place from all of your themes, you're done.

You can also create a common theme and [build on top](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/theme-development%3a-choosing-your-parent) of that.